# How do I make sure a toast is on screen for a specific time before another toast replaces it?

Tags: java, android, toast

I've just started learning Android. I use my MIUI 10 device for debugging.

I've learned the very basic App Lifecycle Program. The problem is, I'm using toasts to show when each of the methods are being called. For eg: When I press the back button, onPause, onStop and onDestroy are 3 SEPERATE toasts that will be displayed.

The problem I'm facing is that MIUI will automatically cancel the current toast if another one is called. So I end up with only onDestroy toast displaying.

Is there a way to ensure I have the toast on screen for a set amount of time before the next one comes? This doesn't have to only apply to this scenario. I need a general solution that will help in the future as well.

Comment: Using a `Toast` as a significant factor in your UI is not recommended. For this sort of "are my methods being called?", use Logcat.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know but I still want know the little things. I probably won't use it as a main factor. I agree with you. But there's no harm in knowing a way to do something like this. It will just make things more clear for me as a person new to Android App Development

Comment: Well, the behavior of `Toast` normally is what you want: each `Toast` is shown for its full time, sequentially. If Xiaomi changed that, I suspect that there is little that you can do about it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe by using threads? I know you can delay a thread. Not really very familiar with it but maybe I could chain them? Like show a toast at the end of each thread? I'm sorry I must be sounding like such a newbie because I am but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MIUI's version of Android has altered the default behaviour where Toasts are displayed sequentially, you can always post them with a delay yourself. The standard delay period for a long toast is 3500ms, and a short toast is 2000ms. With that in mind, you could try something along these lines (untested):

```
final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

void scheduleToasts(String... messages) {
    final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(messages);
    Collections.reverse(list);

    final AtomicInteger countdown = new AtomicInteger(list.size());
    final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        final int count = countdown.getAndDecrement();
        if(count == 0) {
            service.shutdown();
            return;
        }

        uiHandler.post(() -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), list.get(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
    }, 0, 3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

With usage:

```
scheduleToasts("message1", "message2", "message3");
```

Comment: I'll try this out. I'm new to Android so some of the code - not all - is going over my head. But I don't mind as I'll get something new to learn. I'll let you know about if it works

Comment: I use lambdas in this too, which may not work in your IDE/API version, so let me know if any part of it won't compile

Comment: newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() cannot resolve symbol. Am I missing a class to Import? I'm using API level 28

Comment: Resolves OK in my ide -: it should be available to you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()